# Type casting on grid MouseDoubleClick

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, using

I have a datagrid filled with 3 tables data by using join, now I want to cast it on `mousedoubleclick()`. I used " `ToList<>` " , "sender as `ToList<>`",  for casting but not working.

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using now?

Comment: i have done it by using stored procedure and then taking it result as ToList. Thats worked for me